What is the [vocabulary] tag for?
The tag excerpt for vocabulary (513 Qs) is currently:

It's the set of words used by a language, but also all of the words within a language known by a single person.

This breaks the tag excerpt guidelines: we're not meant to define "vocabulary", we're meant to describe when to use the tag.  I'd edit it, only I have no idea when to use this tag.
Question: What is the vocabulary tag for?
In case it helps figure this out, I include some data below:
Questions with this tag

What are the most common Mandarin words for each pinyin syllable?
霹雳与雷霆有什么分别？(What's the difference between these words?)
How do you say "do a plank" in Chinese?
Trust/Believe : “信任” vs “相信”
What does 介绍人 mean?
...
What's the difference between 房子 and 屋?
What is the equivalent of the English word 'Fail' in Mandarin?
Are there word games in Chinese?
What is a good technique for remembering tones?
Character and word frequencies

Questions with only this tag

比方 as a conjunction/连词？？
形式，样式 and 方式 - appearance, style, form, shape...?
投资 vs 投入 - investing / investments?
性质 vs 性格 vs 个性 - all mean personality?
...
What is the most common word in use to describe 'DVD' and what is its measure word
Different names for each of the fingers
What are some common Chinese terms used when playing soccer
Character and word frequencies

(Data Explorer query.)
Questions which were retagged vocabulary
In the last few years, the vocabulary tag was added to these questions...

May 2020: What is the function of "根本" in 这杯咖啡根本不值得花四十元人民币?
August 2016: What is the best translation for 会说? (it was edited away prior, then re-added)
March 2016: Ways to write "strength"
August 2015: What is the meaning of 看在 and 分上?
August 2015: Is "谐仿" an actual word in Chinese?
July 2015: many ways to say Today
June 2015: What's the difference between 帐户 and 账户? (where it was retagged from vocab)
December 2014: Difference between 剧本 and 脚本？ (where it was retagged from vocab)
December 2014: How to properly say "World's fair"
December 2014: Do people use 刻苦 nowadays?  (where it was retagged from vocab)
January 2014: For video games terminology, what is the proper translation for "range"
...

(Data Explorer query.)

How is the tag currently used
It seems the tag is used to loosely identify questions about:

specific terms (then terminology might be fine)
sets of words, as opposed to one single word (then usage, meaning, difference, might be fine according to the actual content of the question)
difference in usage between one or more words, in which case difference or the narrower word-choice seem to make sense

I'll try to analyze the questions you linked one by one.
Analysis of linked questions
Questions with this tag

What are the most common Mandarin words for each pinyin syllable? this one is actually about characters (or words). [pinyin] seems appropriate. Edit I'm a bit in doubt about this one though...
霹雳与雷霆有什么分别？(What's the difference between 霹雳 and 雷霆?) maybe [difference] and/or [word] or [word-choice]. [synonym] seems also fine
How do you say "do a plank" in Chinese? [terminology] and [sport], as it's a term used in sports
Trust/Believe : “信任” vs “相信” [word-choice] seems fine. [difference] might also work
What does 介绍人 mean? maybe [meaning-in-context] or [expression]
...
What's the difference between 房子 and 屋? [word-choice] seems fine
How to say "fail" in Mandarin? (as in "epic fail" in internet memes) [translation] and [internet-slang] seem appropriate. The title might benefit from a review too
Are there word games in Chinese? definitely not about [vocabulary]. [riddle] or [puzzle] might work, though those two tags deserve a separate meta post...
What is a good technique for remembering tones? [tones] seems just fine [vocabulary] might be appropriate.

Questions with only this tag

比方 as a conjunction/连词？？ definitely [grammar]
形式，样式 and 方式 - appearance, style, form, shape...? [difference] and/or [word-choice] seem better
投资 vs 投入 - investing / investments? [difference] and/or [word-choice] seem better
性质 vs 性格 vs 个性 - all mean personality? [difference] and/or [word-choice] seem better
...
What is the most common word in use to describe 'DVD' and what is its measure word [word] and/or [word-choice], optionally also [measure-words]
Different names for each of the fingers this might make a case for [vocabulary], though I wouldn't regret retagging as [translation] + [word]
What are some common Chinese terms used when playing soccer definitely [terminology], plus optionally [sport]
Character and word frequencies [resources] seem fine (and necessary)

Questions which were retagged vocabulary
In the last few years, the vocabulary tag was added to these questions...

May 2020: What is the function of "根本" in 这杯咖啡根本不值得花四十元人民币? [usage] seems better
August 2016: What is the best translation for 会说? [translation] seems just fine. [word-choice] might help disambiguate
March 2016: Ways to write "strength" [word] or [word-choice] might be fine
August 2015: What is the meaning of 看在 and 分上? [vocabulary] seems unnecessary
August 2015: Is "谐仿" an actual word in Chinese? [vocabulary] seems unnecessary
July 2015: many ways to say Today [vocabulary] seems unnecessary
June 2015: What's the difference between 帐户 and 账户? [usage], [difference], [word-choice] seem fine
December 2014: Difference between 剧本 and 脚本？ [vocabulary] seems unnecessary
December 2014: How to properly say "World's fair" [translation] seem fine
December 2014: Do people use 刻苦 nowadays? [colloquialism] [usage] or [meaning] seem better
January 2014: For video games terminology, what is the proper translation for "range" [terminology] seem better, optionally [technology]

Can we find proper usage guidelines for this tag?
tl;dr yes.
I think we can conclude that the tag, given its current definition, isn't used properly. Even more so, it doesn't even appear to be very useful, given the other tags that more meaningfully can describe the questions we examined here.
I can imagine questions where this tag might actually be appropriate, given its definition. For example:

"How can I improve my Mandarin vocabulary" (might even be off-topic as opinion-based...)
"How many words are required to read a modern newspaper?"

So the tag might be used productively when:

asking questions about one's own vocabulary, like memorization or learning techniques, usage of flashcards, HSK vocabulary requirements, etc.
asking questions about general vocabulary that can be answered more or less objectively (e.g. quoting research outcomes), as total known hanzi in Chinese, minimum words to read newspapers/books/texts/papers, research about average number of chars/words known by different age groups, and the like
questions about Cantonese-specific Standard Written Chinese that don't focus on a particular character or word.

Conclusion
Given the above, I propose to clarify the tag usage via excerpt/wiki, and proceed with retagging.

I found Sichuanese : any tips to learn some vocabulary? and How can I sort a list of words by frequency or by hsk level? and Web Developer Vocabulary.

Maybe it's used correctly for Fridge and Freezer Beyond 冰箱, which is about refrigerator vocabulary.
